# getting errors when am building the cordova windows application

Tags: windows, cordova, visual-studio-2015, build

1>------ Build started: Project: InsightsGoApp, Configuration: Debug Windows-x86 ------
    1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 8.11.3 (x64) and npm.
    1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
    1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
    1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.42
    1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
    1>  ------ Cordova tools 6.1.1 already installed.
    1>  ------ Build Settings:
    1>  ------ Build Settings:
    1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\bld\Windows-x86\Debug
    1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\bin\Windows-x86\Debug
    1>  ------    buildCommand: build
    1>  ------    platform: Windows-x86
    1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: windows
    1>  ------    configuration: Debug
    1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
    1>  ------    projectName: InsightsGoApp
    1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp
    1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\sheakbar\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\MDA\vs-npm\2.14.9
    1>  ------    buildTarget: LocalMachine
    1>  ------    language: en-US
    1>  ------ Platform windows already exists
    1>  ------ Updating plugins
    1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1,cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@3.0.0
    1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins: cordova-plugin-device@2.0.2,cordova-plugin-network-information@2.0.1,cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.3

```
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: windows
1>  Executing "before_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "before_build"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Searching PlatformJson files for differences between project vs. platform installed plugins
1>  No differences found between project and windows platform. Continuing...
1>  Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for windows at C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\config.xml
1>  Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific windows config.xml
1>  Found "merges/windows" folder. Copying its contents into the windows project.
1>  Merging and updating files from [www, platforms\windows\platform_www, merges\windows] to platforms\windows\www
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\cordova-js-src\confighelper.js platforms\windows\www\cordova-js-src\confighelper.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\cordova-js-src\exec.js platforms\windows\www\cordova-js-src\exec.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\cordova-js-src\platform.js platforms\windows\www\cordova-js-src\platform.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\cordova_plugins.js platforms\windows\www\cordova_plugins.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\global_constants.js platforms\windows\www\global_constants.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\global_data.js platforms\windows\www\global_data.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\global_static.js platforms\windows\www\global_static.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\global_variables.js platforms\windows\www\global_variables.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\index.html platforms\windows\www\index.html (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-device\src\windows\DeviceProxy.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-device\src\windows\DeviceProxy.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-device\www\device.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-device\www\device.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\windows\FileProxy.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\src\windows\FileProxy.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryEntry.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryEntry.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryReader.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\DirectoryReader.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Entry.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Entry.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\File.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\File.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileEntry.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileEntry.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileError.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileError.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileReader.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileReader.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileSystem.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileSystem.js (updated file)



1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadOptions.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadOptions.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadResult.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileUploadResult.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileWriter.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\FileWriter.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Flags.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Flags.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\LocalFileSystem.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\LocalFileSystem.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Metadata.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\Metadata.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ProgressEvent.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\ProgressEvent.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\browser\isChrome.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\browser\isChrome.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystemPaths.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystemPaths.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystems.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\fileSystems.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\requestFileSystem.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\requestFileSystem.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-file\www\resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\src\windows\InAppBrowserProxy.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\src\windows\InAppBrowserProxy.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\www\inappbrowser.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-inappbrowser\www\inappbrowser.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\src\windows\NetworkInfoProxy.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\src\windows\NetworkInfoProxy.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\www\Connection.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\www\Connection.js (updated file)
1>    copy  platforms\windows\platform_www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\www\network.js platforms\windows\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-network-information\www\network.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\scripts\Common\common.css platforms\windows\www\scripts\Common\common.css (updated file)
1>    copy  www\scripts\Common\jquery-2.1.4.min.js platforms\windows\www\scripts\Common\jquery-2.1.4.min.js (updated file)
1>    copy  www\scripts\Common\underscore-min-new.js platforms\windows\www\scripts\Common\underscore-min-new.js (updated file)
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build warning : Warning: The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (24x24): res/icons/windows/icon-24.png
1>MDAVSCLI : warning : The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (24x24): res/icons/windows/icon-24.png


1>MSBUILD : cordova-build warning : Warning: The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (48x48): res/icons/windows/icon-48.png
1>MDAVSCLI : warning : The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (48x48): res/icons/windows/icon-48.png
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build warning : Warning: The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (55x55): res/icons/windows/icon-55.png
1>MDAVSCLI : warning : The following image was skipped because it has an unsupported size (55x55): res/icons/windows/icon-55.png
1>  Updating icons and splash screens at platforms\windows\images
1>  Prepared windows project successfully
1>  Executing "pre_package"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Executing "after_prepare"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-document-viewer" in config.xml. Installing to the project
1>  Executing "before_plugin_add"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Calling plugman.fetch on plugin "git+https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer.git"
1>  Fetching plugin "git+https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer.git" via git clone
1>  ------ Copied C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\bin\Windows-x86\Debug\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Metadata.Overrides.props to platforms\windows\Microsoft.AppxPackage.Metadata.Overrides.props
1>  ------ Building platform: windows
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Executing "before_compile"  hook for all plugins.
1>  Reading build config file: C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\build.json
1>  getLatestMatchingMSBuild
1>  getLatestMSBuild
1>  Searching for available MSBuild versions...
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.5 /v MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.0 /v MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0 /v MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0 /v MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0 /v MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Command finished with error code 1: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.5,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Command finished with error code 1: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\15.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Found MSBuild v12.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\14.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Found MSBuild v14.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0,/v,MSBuildToolsPath
1>  Found MSBuild v4.0 at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\
1>  Using MSBuild v14.0 from C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
1>  Building project: C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj
1>      Configuration : debug
1>      Platform      : x86
1>      Buildflags    : /p:AppxBundle=Never
1>      MSBuildTools  : C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin
1>  Running command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows" /s /v InstallationFolder /reg:32
1>  Command finished with error code 0: C:\WINDOWS\system32\reg.exe query,HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows,/s,/v,InstallationFolder,/reg:32
1>  buildProject spawn: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild [ 'C:\\Aleem\\Development\\InsightsGoApp\\InsightsGoApp\\platforms\\windows\\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj',
1>    '/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal',
1>    '/nologo',
1>    '/p:Configuration=debug',
1>    '/p:Platform=x86',
1>    '/p:AppxBundle=Never' ] { stdio: 'inherit' }
1>  Running command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe" C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal /nologo /p:Configuration=debug /p:Platform=x86 /p:AppxBundle=Never
1>    prebuild.js: Patching platform `10`
1>    - Injected `base.js` reference to `/www/index.html`
1>    - Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.WinJS.2.0\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from /www/index.html
1>    - Removing /( *)(<script\s+(?:type="text\/javascript"\s+)?src="\/\/Microsoft.Phone.WinJS.2.1\/js\/base.js">\s*<\/script>)(\s*)/ from /www/index.html
1>    CordovaApp.Windows10 -> C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\AppPackages\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.1_x86_debug_Test\CordovaApp.Windows10_0.0.1.1_x86_debug.appx


1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(2748,5): error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\AppxPackage\Add-AppDevPackage.ps1" because it was not found. [C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj]
1>  Command finished with error code 1: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe C:\Aleem\Development\InsightsGoApp\InsightsGoApp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows10.jsproj,/clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debug,/p:Platform=x86,/p:AppxBundle=Never
1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error : code: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
1>code : error C: \Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1 No valid MSBuild was detected for the selected target: Error C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe: Command failed with exit code 1
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==`enter code here`========
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had endless errors when trying to use the Windows 10 SDK, it's the worst SDK ever made. Try using the WP 8.1 SDK, you can create apps for both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile using it and VS2015, by selecting *Windows Universal* as target.

You may need to uninstall absolutely EVERYTHING and then install the 8.1 SDK from the VS setup program, if you don't have it already installed. You can also use the standalone [SDK 8.1 Update 1 installer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive). You need to download the one labeled **Windows Phone 8.1 Update and Emulators**.

Last: If you decide to switch to VS2017, [forget about WP8.1 compatibility](https://www.andreszsogon.com/visual-studio-2017-and-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/), as it does not work with the 8.1 SDK, that's why I keep using VS2015 and the 8.1 SDK.